# Do I need to generate the .ensime directory when adding a dependency to an sbt project?

Tags: scala, emacs, ensime

Do I need to generate the `.ensime` directory again with `sbt gen-ensime` when adding a new dependency to an sbt project?

Comment: I always do so. ensime downloads source jars and probably do more job.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is required. You also need to restart the ensime server, but that's pretty fast. There is some support in the Emacs client to do this automatically.

You could manually hack the `.ensime` file if you don't want to wait for SBT, but then you won't get sources/javadocs.